# Ivy : Consequences of modifying "checkconsitency"

Tags: java, maven, ivy, consistency

I have two related questions about ivy:

Note that the docs for Ivy's "checkconsitency" flag say :

"The checkconsistency attribute allows you to enable or disable consistency checking between what is expected by Ivy when it finds a module descriptor, and what the module descriptor actually contains."

**1) What is meant here by "consistency checking" ?  Why would Ivy "expect" a certain module a-priori ?**

and

**2) How does checkconsistency differ from the checkmodified ?  It seems that these might be redundant in some way, but I'm not quite sure.**

For context - I'm not much of an expert on the internals of how nexus/maven repos are set up - so any important contextual information to help me understand the idea behind these ivy "checks" would probably be very helpful.

Comment: interesting. It seems to handle inconsistent maven poms :https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IVY-163